# Uploading image for specific user so other users can't see that specific image

Tags: php, html

How do i upload an image for a specific user so that when he logs in only he can see the picture but not other users? Here is my code snippet. I have uploaded an image for an user from my associative array. But when other users log in from that array they can still view the image and information already given for the first user.

P.S. i have not used jquery/javascript. I need to solve this using basic php only.

```
        <form action='upload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' name='mfm'>
        if (isset($_SESSION["userlogin"])==true)

        {   

        if(file_exists($_SESSION["t"]))

        {
        echo "
            Photo: You already have a picture uploaded! <br>

         ";
        }
        else 
        {
        echo "  

        <br>
        Upload a Picture: <input type='file' name='fileToUpload'>
        <br>

        <input type='submit' value='Upload Now' name='submit'>  
        <br>

        </form> ";
        }

        echo " 

        Name: Anybody <br>

        ID:12 <br>

        <a href='logout.php' > Log out </a>
        </form>
        ";
        }
```

Now for the upload.php file

```
    <?php
     session_start();
     $_SESSION["s"]= $_FILES['fileToUpload'] ['tmp_name'];
     $_SESSION["t"]=$_FILES['fileToUpload'] ['name'];

     $mime=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'];
     $_SESSION["type"]=explode("/",$mime); 


     if($_SESSION["type"][0]=="image")
     {
     echo "Congratulations you uploaded a file! 
     <br>
     <a href='UserPage.php' > Back </a>";

     move_uploaded_file($_SESSION["s"], $_SESSION["t"]);
     }
     else echo "Please choose image file only 
     <br>
     <a href='UserPage.php' > Go back to previous page </a>";

     ?>
```

Comment: How do you log in from an array? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: By using associative array in session variable

Comment: Tie the file name of the image to the user name. Then, the only image someone can see when they log in is their own image.

Comment: Did you clear SESSION on log out?

Comment: @RaimondasKazlauskas: YEs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am in mobile and I can't quite read the code and test it, but.. what 
might help you out is to test if the specific user is signed in. So what I mean just put an IF statement checking if his name is say "Alan" to show him that image. If you need further help make sure to reply and I'll do my best to get back to you!